# "Export to Excel" - Database Connections Data - SP2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, external-list, external-data

We have few "Database Connections" created in SP Designer 2010 and I used the "Data view" web part to display the database connections' data.

Is it possible to export this data to an excel?

Answer (score 4):

**Unfortunately,** it's not possible!

The `Export to Excel` option is **not available** in the `External List` in SharePoint 2010. Check the full limitations list at my article [External List limitations in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/)

> **Note:** The `Export to Excel` option is **available** for `External List` in SharePoint 2013.

---

**[Update]**

**Unfortunately,** there is no OOTB option to export Data View with an external database connection in SharePoint.

But you can use Jquery as a workaround to achieve that as I mentioned at [Export Data View to excel in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/22/export-data-view-to-excel-in-sharepoint-2016-2013/)

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about BCS or Database connections in SP2013? In SP2013, For Database Connections, I dont see an option to "Export to Excel".

Comment: I talk about the Export to Excel option in the external list that created from external content type in sharepoint designer, and you asked about it in sp 2010 that is not available, but it available in sp 2013

Comment: My query is not related to "External content Types" but it is regarding "Datasources". I have created few "Database connections" and want that data to be exportable in Sharepoint

Comment: @George Sorry for that I confused with the data connection and BCS let me update my answer with the detail steps that related to your question

Comment: @George before I update my answer, could you please try the following: it's for sharePoint 2010 - Open your page that host data view via SharePoint designer 2010.
- Select the data view web part and right click and select properties - in the properties check the  'SharePoint Toolbars ' as shown at https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/ab834292-d077-4948-abf6-787f1b23012e.gif ,  show the page in browser and check the toolbar > actions > export to spreadsheet

Comment: By the way, **SharePoint Toolbars** is not available in SPD 2013 and I am working on my side to find a workaround Please feedback me if it works or not :)

Comment: In SP2010,when i right click on the webpart and select properties, i don't see the properties as displayed in ur image,rather i get only Tag properties.  I can see the "SharePoint Toolbar" in the ribbon, (Design --> Options)however it is grayed out.

Comment: @George I just needed a confirmation from you in SP 2010, where I tried this in 2013 and it's also grayed out. , Now it looks like it's not possible as OOTB in SP 2010 and SP 2013 So Today I will try to update my answer with a simple workaround to be able to export the data view with external database source.